# Which Wiimote works best with Wii U?

Tags: nintendo-wii, wii-u, wiimote

I just purchased a Wii U (with the gamepad) and a Nyko Pro controller. The last Nintendo system I owned was Gamecube and as such I am out of touch with Wii accessories. I understand a number of them work with the Wii U, but I'm confused about which work with eachother.

From what I can see online these are what are available:

- Wiimote

  Wiimote Plus

  Wii Nunchuck

  Wii MotionPlus

Here are my questions:

1. What is the difference between the Wiimote and Wiimote Plus?

   Which of these are compatible with the others?

   With a Nyko Pro controller and the Gamepad do I really need any of these for a Wii U?

   Anything else I should know?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Not sure why this is marked as "primarily opinion based." I'm asking for the differences and compatabilites between 4 Nintendo products. I hope its not because I used the word best in the title and no one read the question.

Comment: Which accessory you use will depend on how it's implemented in-game.  Some might work very well with Motionplus, others might be beter with the Nunchuck.  If you can narrow this down to a single, specific game, that might be something we can help with.  Otherwise, it's really just a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of the old Wii controllers and accessories *still work* with a Wii U, as long as the games are prepared for them.

The [Wii Remote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii_Remote) is the standard controller as it was originally released with the Wii.

The [Wii Nunchuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii_Remote#Nunchuk) and [Wii MotionPlus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii_MotionPlus) are *accessories* to a Wii Remote - they plug into the bottom. The Nunchuck is a secondary controller with an analog stick, and the MotionPlus is a device that contains additional hardware for detecting movement more accurately. Note that they are *not* independent controllers; you have to plug them into a Wii Remote.

A [Wii Remote Plus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii_Remote#Wii_Remote_Plus) is simply a Wii Remote with a *built-in* MotionPlus - there is no other differences, and it will work as a regular Wii Remote for any game. This is usually a better choice than the standard Wii Remote, since [some games require a MotionPlus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_games_that_support_Wii_MotionPlus#Wii_U), but if you aren't going to play any of those, then it doesn't really matter, and you could always get a MotionPlus at a later date if you need one.

So, do you actually *need* a Wii Remote? It depends on the games you're going to play. If you're going to play local multiplayer, that almost always requires another Wii Remote per extra person (Game & Wario is a rare exception to this). If you're going to play any Wii games (including , you need one Wii Remote per person.

If you're only ever going to play single-player Wii U games, then you probably don't *need* one - but you may still *want* a Wii Remote: Although almost every Wii U game can be played exclusively with the gamepad, there is at least one exception (Wii Sports Club), and more might show up later (e.g. the next Zelda game, if they keep the sword controls from Skyward Sword).

Furthermore, many games *allow* the use of a Wii Remote - you might prefer that for some titles, especially if it doesn't also support the Pro controller.

If none of those reasons apply to you, then you're likely good to go with the controllers you already have - and if a game comes along that makes you change your mind, the Wii controllers are still going to be available then.

Comment: Thanks, I learned a lot. I think I'll go with the Wiimote Plus.

Answer (score -5):

1. Wii motion plus is better for wii fit or just dance.
2. Wii mote, wii motion plus and nyko pro.
3. No
   4.No.

Comment: Please expand your answers.  Why is Motionplus better for Wii Fit or Just Dance?  Why wouldn't they be needed for a Wii U?  We're looking for expertise; answering with the bare minimum doesn't really help anyone at all.

Comment: And Wii Fit doesn't even make use of the Motion Plus.